# Zoom in and Zoom Out Pygame

Tags: python, pygame, zooming, pixel

So, I'm working with pygame in python 2.7.9 and I'm trying to make some kind of zoom, to view details of a fractal.

I can easily draw a Sierpinski triangle using polygons, my idea is to zoom a area of the triangle and see details of the depth without pixelation.

So far, I can zoom in but the surface gets pixelated

Is there anyway to do this?

Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried re-drawing the object based on whatever formulas you're using to draw the fractal when you "zoom in"? You would need to adjust the formula for scale of course. This means a lot of things will have to be adjusted, the thickness of your draw-lines for example.

Answer (score 0):

First make a canvas and triangle with a big size and Zoom out. So when you zoom in, it won't get pixelated.

Comment: Sorry but, what is "big canvas"?

Comment: I meant take a couple times more pixels you take for the canvas.

Comment: So I meant what is canvas, sorry I'm new at UIs

Comment: Canvas is what you paint the objects on. I meant just make everything bigger than what they normally are.